# Chart.js yAxis rotation

Tags: javascript, charts

Is there the solution to rotate just title for yAxis, similar to https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.rotation

Comment: Specify whether you use highcharts.js or chart.js. They are 2 different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your question is connected to Highcharts library or Chart.js.

If you are using Highcharts - here is a solution:
As I understand you want to rotate only the title of yAxis the same way as labels are rotated in a sample which you sent. So this code should be a solution:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
    rotation: 90
  }
},
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wc85xm6y/)